# filter mongoose documents based on the specific fields and attributes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm developing a website using the MEAN stack (MongoDB/Express/Angular/Node).

I have a product schema with 12 different fields/properties, including size, color, brand, model, etc. What is the best and most efficient way to filter products, in Angular or on the server-side?And how can i chain the results if the client had selected more than one property?What would that look like?

Comment: Do it through mongoose.  Getting all of the documents back in your code and then filtering it is highly inefficient.  Take a look at the documentation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Comment: Was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there will be a lot of products, it will be too much to download to the client in order to filter using Angular. It doesn't scale very well. As the list of products gets bigger and bigger, it will be less and less performant. The better way would, generally, be to let MongoDB do the filtering for you. It's very fast.

But, you can control the filtering from Angular by posting to the server the filtering term you want on the endpoint used for that method of filtering, for example, using the *http module*

```
http.post('/api/filter/' + methodOfFiltering, { 'term': termtoFilterBy },  function(dataReturned) {
    // use dataReturned to do something with the data
});
```

Put this in an angular service method, so you can inject it into any of your controllers/components.

Create an endpoint that will use the method and the keyword in the mongoose query. I'm assuming that you're using Express for your server routes.

```
app.post('/api/filter/:method', function(req, res) {

    var method = req.params.method;
    var termToFilterBy = req.body.term;

    productSchema.find({method: termToFilterBy}, function(err, products) {
        res.send(products);
    });

});
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I admit that I am quite new in this area. However, I'm asking myself, if passing a request parameter *directly* to the DB would not open up SQL-injection-like security holes? I.e., would you recommend this practice in production as well?

Comment: Well, you may want to add some checks to make sure that only requests of certain methods and certain filter terms are being submitted. In this case if the field (e.g. 'size', 'color') doesn't exist, at all. You'll probably get an error and if the filter term doesn't match anything, you'll get back an empty array. I don't see how anything could get added to your database through this method though.

Comment: This *post* is just a smarter version of a *get*. I don't think something like SQL-injection is a concern here, but I'll let others weigh in on that.

Comment: your answer was very helpful,, thanks , but just a little question, how can i chain the results , because user can have multiple choices at the same time, so i should send the response through the first find query, back to the db, that if the user selects another attribute , we handle it on the results we already have from older requests.

Comment: I would recommend typing up a new question with more details.